# Accessing source files found in HTML from django app internals

Tags: html, django, directory, filepath

This might seem like a strange request, but I'm dealing with a code base written by someone who was not a fan of documentation and this seems to be the best approach to my problem. Basically on this site we have a number of videos with references transcripts and I'm trying to index the original transcript files for elasticsearch.

Basically I'm at a point where I can get the string that is used as the source in the html, and I've determined the actual filename of the transcript that I'm looking for, but I'm not sure exactly how to link the two up.

I know Django does some kind of path magic when it comes to these things, but I'm not hugely familiar with Django and I'm getting close to a deadline and so any help would be appreciated. Essentially I have an HTML element of the form:

```
<div id="id" class="video" file-name="OEoXaMPEzfM" data-caption-asset-path="/transcript/directory/">
```

How exactly should I go about actually opening the file referenced by this html element from within the django app? Is there a good reference for wrapping my head around this kind of stuff that's worth reading? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the source in this way:
In your django shell, (`./manage.py shell`)

```
> from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve

> func, args, kwargs = resolve("/transcript/directory/")
> module = func.__module__
```

`func` is the name of the function, and `module` is the name of the package it is found in.

You can read up more about URL resolution [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse)

You can also access the source code [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/urlresolvers.py) to see how it is implemented.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what exactly resolve is doing here?

Comment: just added a link which  can give you more details - basically, the method is getting the registered urls, and finding which view needs to be called

Comment: Awesome, it'll take a while for me to get through this, but it seems to be what I'm looking for.